# Calculating first and second derivative of negative exponent

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given $f(x) = (x+2)^{-1} $ is my logic and result correct for calculating first and second derivatives ? :

First derivative :

$$\frac{df}{dx}=-1(x+2)^{-1-1} =(-x-2)^{-2}$$

Second derivative :

$$\frac{d^2f}{dx^x}=-2(-x-2)^{-2-1} =(2x+2)^{-3}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately you aren't right.

Remind that $\frac{d}{dx} x^n = n\cdot x^{n-1}$ and $(u(v))' = u'(v)\cdot v'$.

These rules lead us to

$$\frac{d}{dx} (x+2)^{-1} = -1\cdot (x+2)^{-2} = -\frac{1}{(x+2)^2}$$
and
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2} (x+2)^{-1} = \frac{d}{dx} \left(-\frac{1}{(x+2)^2}\right) = -2\cdot -(x+2)^{-3} = \frac{2}{(x+2)^3}$$

Answer (score 1):

a littler mistake we get $$f'(x)=-(x+2)^{-2}$$ and $$f''(x)=2(x+2)^{-3}$$